# Is a UK university student loan riba, and if so, is it "necessary" if I have no other means to pay for education or to provide for my family?

Tags: riba, finance, education, loan

I’ve heard student loans deemed as Ribaa.  However, for a UK university student loan, the conditions are documented:

> How much you repay
>
> You pay back 9% of your income over the minimum amount of:
>
> - £17,750 for Plan 1 - this amount changes on 6 April every year
> - £21,000 for Plan 2
>
> Interest starts being added to your loan from when you get your first payment. How much you pay depends on which plan you’re on.
> <sub>[Repaying your student loan](https://www.gov.uk/repaying-your-student-loan/what-you-pay)</sub>

Is this classed as Ribaa?  I think it is.

And is it not classed as a "necessity" if I have no other means to pay for education, or if it's used to provide for my family?

Comment: Related: [Is forced interest a sin to the payer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39331/is-forced-interest-a-sin-to-the-payer)